# Import node module with Webpack

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webstorm, angular-cli

[image]

WebStorm tells me it can't resolve the file 'base-64' which is a node module I recently installed via npm install. However, I don't get an error in my application and I can use the base64 variable without issues.

What do I need to change to remove the error?

- Angular/cli 1.1.3
- webpack 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use third-party scripts with angular-cli, you need:

Install de package: 
npm install base-64

Import package in **.angular-cli.json** scripts:

```
 ...,
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/base-64/base64.js"
 ],
 ...
```

After that you need check if the installed package has export modules to use in typescript, as:
[image: @angular]

```
/**
 * The module that includes all the basic Angular directives like {@link NgIf}, {@link NgForOf}, ...
 *
 * @stable
 */
export declare class CommonModule {
}
```

In this case for base64 you didn`t have a module then you can use:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare let base64: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';

  ngOnInit() { 
    console.log(base64);
  }
}
```